# I can't create an AngularJS controler to return $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a controller to change the `ng-model` to be different from the input

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="NumPA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">X do P.A.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2" ng-controller="NumberChanged">
        <input type="text" id="NumPA" class="form-control" ng-model="NumPA" data-mask="99.999 / 9999" placeholder="XX.XXX / XXXX"/>
        <pre>Model: {{NumPA | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function NumberChanged($scope) {
    $scope = $scope.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
}
```

What I want is to get an XXXXXXXXX number inside Model (NumPA)

What I'm doing wrong?

**==UPDATE==**

Why this work,

```
function NumberChanged($scope) {
        alert($scope.NumPA);
}
```

but this not?

```
    function NumberChanged($scope) {
         $scope.NumPA = $scope.NumPA.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    }
```

My model stays like this:

```
    Model: {{NumPA | json}}
```

And I want it like this

```
    Model: 01282014
```

**==UPDATE 2==**

Ok, Now I'm trying this:

```
function NumberChanged($scope) {
    if(! typeof $scope.NumPA === 'undefined'){
        $scope.NumPA = $scope.NumPA.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    };
}
```

there is no console erros.

```
  Model: "12.345 / 6789"
```

And I expect:

```
 Model: "123456789"
```

**==UPDATE 3==**

I tried this but not did what I need:

```
function NumberChanged($scope) {
    var entrada = $scope.NumPA;
    if(! typeof entrada === 'undefined'){
        entrada.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    };
    $scope.NumPA = entrada;
}
```

Comment: You must have a `$scope.NumPA` defined.

Comment: `$scope` is not a string, you can't do that. However you can do it on `$scope.NumPA`

Comment: what I need to do to fix it? Still not working...

Comment: Can you look inside the console to see if an error is logged? if your angular didn't compile this: `Model: {{NumPA | json}}` then there is an error...

Comment: @PatrickEvans it is not a bitwise because it's an angular expression. it's just a **filter**. angular expression are not evaluated with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mutilating the reference to `$scope.numPA` by replacing it. Add the logic into a $scope watch and assign it to another variable thats not your `$scope.numPA`

```
function NumberChanged($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('NumPA', function(newVal) {
        $scope.NumPA2 = $scope.NumPA.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    });
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4A756/1/

Comment: My $scope.NumPA still same as if I do not create `function NumberChanged` Please, see update 3